# Epson Workforce 30 on Jammy?

Tags: 22.04, epson

I was using an Epson Workforce 30 printer for years under 16.04, and it worked just fine.

Recently, I used a system crash as motivation to get off my backside and upgrade to 22.04.

Now, I can't get the printer to work to save my life. I've spent days on this thing, tinkering with CUPS, and gutenprint (installed via snap software). I'm ready to throw the printer away and buy whatever the compatible list says will work.

Someone please save my sanity?

Comment: Does Ubuntu not detect the printer at all?

Comment: Add more details like how is the printer connected, USB, WiFi, Ethernet cable, or parallel port? Have you installed the driver from Epson's website? Do they install or fail to install? If fail, please add the error messages.

Comment: What are the sub-versions of your Epson Workforce 3xyy, so what is "x", and what is "yy". Is your printer still supported by Epson with a Linux driver? A CUPS driver would be useful for you.